# Python SocketIO Emit not sending

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to emit and event with socketio. The print before starting the thread is executed normally. But the socketio emit unfortunately does not work. Any solutions?

```
def notifyAboutLidar():
    print("PRINT")
    thread = threading.Thread(target=socketio.emit('response', {'status': 'CONNECTED'}))
    thread.start()
    # socketio.emit('response', {'status': 'CONNECTED'})
```

Comment: `target=` needs function's name without `()` and arguments, And `Thread` needs second parameter `args=('response', {'status': 'CONNECTED'})`  --- `Thread( target=socketio.emit, args=('response', {'status': 'CONNECTED'}) )`

Comment: I don't understand why to run it in thread. First: it may need more time to start thread than sending it directly. Second: it may not work in separated thread  - it may need to run `socketio` only in current thread.